# Graphic novel with a woman, deep sea experiment, Abe Sapien-looking monsters killing people

Tags: story-identification, comics

I absolutely cannot find this comic anywhere. I read it maybe 5 or 10 years ago. It had amazing artwork, similar to Rick Remender. It was kinda like the series Low, but not quite.

There was a young woman protagonist, and she had to go on a deep sea voyage to find something at the bottom of the sea. Can't remember the details. But there was this Abe Sapien looking sea creature they kept in a giant glass tank. The fish people eventually started killing people. They had hallucinogenic properties and could make people see things that weren't there....and they would use this to their advantage and absolutely slaughter the humans.

There were two main story branches. One with the young woman scientist lady kinda in modern day, discovering these deep sea fishmen monsters. And then it would jump to the distant future with another young woman protagonist with her pet dolphin. Kinda post apocalyptic. God, I can't remember the name! And it's hard to seach for "comics based on deep sea" etc. Does this sound familiar to any of you?

Comment: The comic was called The Wake!!!! Someone answered it on another board. Thank you guys so much for being willing to help. I'm new to this board so I don't know how to mark my question as "answered" or how to delete it.

Comment: You don't have to delete it. I actually find some great ides about what to read next in the "story-identification" tag...

Answer (score 5):

According to the OP comment above, this comic is called *The Wake*, by Scott Snyder and Sean Murphy, published by Vertigo in 2014. Per the [publisher's summary](https://www.vertigocomics.com/characters/the-wake):

> When the Department of Homeland Security approaches Marine Biologist
>   Lee Archer for help with a new threat, she finds herself plunged into
>   the depths of the Arctic Circle to a secret, underwater oil rig known
>   as the “Ghost Rig” with other scientists specializing in various
>   biological fields. There, they discover something both miraculous and
>   terrifying—a brand-new species that may just be the missing link… or a
>   link to something even bigger. But when things go horribly wrong, and
>   people begin to go missing, this scientific safe haven will turn into
>   a house of horrors at the bottom of the ocean.

[image]

Comment: Hey @VleetXay, if you want to, you can accept this answer to show it's the correct one. I know someone else on a board found it, but based on your comment, someone here did some work to write an answer out of that. And it'll look nicer if accepted.